# Transition issue with card flip style login form Vuejs where card is not staying in place when entering or leaving

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to style a login/signup component in Vue.js where I want it so that when you flick between the two, that it flips the card I have, however, the issue I am having is during the transition. I cannot seem to get it working. When the one card tranforms out it moves down and to the right and when the other comes in, it transforms from the bottom right and into position. It is really hard to describe the issue.

Below is the webpage design (although navbar is a separate component)

[image]

Below are a couple images to show what the transformation is doing.
[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

The code for the component is as follows:

```
<template>
  <main class="login-body">
    <transition name="flip">
      <div class="login-box" v-if="currentForm === 'login'">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form @submit.prevent>
          <div class="user-box">
            <input v-model="email" type="text" name="username" required />
            <label>Email</label>
          </div>
          <div class="user-box">
            <input
              v-model="password"
              type="password"
              name="password"
              required
            />
            <label>Password</label>
          </div>
          <button @click="signIn">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
        <p>Not Signed Up? <span @click="toggleForm">Sign Up</span></p>
      </div></transition
    >
    <transition name="flip-reverse">
      <div class="login-box" v-if="currentForm === 'register'">
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <form @submit.prevent>
          <div class="user-box">
            <input v-model="email" type="text" name="username" required />
            <label>Username</label>
          </div>
          <div class="user-box">
            <input
              v-model="password"
              type="password"
              name="password"
              required
            />
            <label>Password</label>
          </div>
          <div class="user-box">
            <input
              v-model="confirmPassword"
              type="password"
              name="confirm password"
              required
            />
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
          </div>
          <button @click="signUp">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
        <p>Already Signed Up? <span @click="toggleForm">Sign In</span></p>
      </div></transition
    >
  </main>
  <!-- <main class="home-container">
    <div class="register-card">
      <form
        @submit.prevent
        class="registration-form"
        v-if="currentForm === 'register'"
      >
        <input v-model="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
        <input v-model="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <button type="submit" @click="signIn">Sign In</button>
        <p>Not Signed Up? <span @click="toggleForm">Sign Up</span></p>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="login-card">
      <form @submit.prevent class="login-form" v-if="currentForm === 'login'">
        <input v-model="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
        <input v-model="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <input
          v-model="confirmPassword"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Confirm Password"
        />
        <button type="submit" @click="signUp">Sign up</button>
        <p>Already Signed Up? <span @click="toggleForm">Sign In</span></p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </main> -->
</template>

<script>
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
export default {
  name: "HomeView",
  data() {
    return {
      currentForm: "login",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleForm() {
      this.currentForm = this.currentForm === "login" ? "register" : "login";
    },
    async signUp() {
      if (
        this.email === "" ||
        this.password === "" ||
        this.confirmPassword === ""
      ) {
        alert("You must fill in all required fields");
        return;
      }
      if (this.password !== this.confirmPassword) {
        alert("Passwords do not match");
        return;
      }
      if (
        !this.password.match(
          /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/
        )
      ) {
        alert(
          "Password must contain at least 8 characters, one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character"
        );
        return;
      }
      try {
        await Auth.signUp({
          username: this.email,
          password: this.password,
          attributes: {
            email: this.email,
          },
        });
        await Auth.signIn({ username: this.email, password: this.password });
        this.email = "";
        this.password = "";
        this.confirmPassword = "";
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.code === "UsernameExistsException") {
          alert("Username already exists");
        }
        console.log(err);
      }
    },
    async signIn() {
      if (this.email === "" || this.password === "") {
        alert("You must fill in all required fields");
        return;
      }
      try {
        await Auth.signIn({ username: this.email, password: this.password });
        this.email = "";
        this.password = "";
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
/* main > .home-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

main > .register-card {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}
main > .login-card {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}

main > .register-card > form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
} */

/* html {
  height: 100%;
} */

main > .login-body {
  position: relative;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(#141e30, #243b55);
}

.login-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #0d1520;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px #0f1824;
}

.login-box h2 {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #03e9f4;
  text-align: center;
}

.login-box .user-box {
  position: relative;
}

.login-box .user-box input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.login-box .user-box label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.login-box .user-box input:focus ~ label,
.login-box .user-box input:valid ~ label {
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  color: #03e9f4;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.login-body form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 15px;
}

.login-box form button {
  background: #0d1520;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #03e9f4;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-top: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border: none;
}

.login-box form button:hover {
  background: #03e9f4;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4, 0 0 25px #03e9f4, 0 0 50px #03e9f4,
    0 0 100px #03e9f4;
}

.login-box button span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.login-box p span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.login-box button span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim1 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes btn-anim1 {
  0% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

.login-box button span:nth-child(2) {
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim2 2s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes btn-anim2 {
  0% {
    top: -100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}

.login-box button span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim3 2s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes btn-anim3 {
  0% {
    right: -100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    right: 100%;
  }
}

.login-box button span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim4 2s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes btn-anim4 {
  0% {
    bottom: -100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    bottom: 100%;
  }
}

.login-box p {
  color: #03e8f481;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.login-box p span {
  color: #03e9f4;
}

.flip-enter-active,
.flip-leave-active {
  transition: all 10s;
  transition-delay: 0.5;
}

.flip-enter-from {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.flip-leave-to {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-reverse-enter-active,
.flip-leave-active {
  transition: all 10s;
  transition-delay: 0.5;
}

.flip-reverse-enter-from {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.flip-reverse-leave-to {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
</style>
```

Any help to fix this issue would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things here you need to do:

Firstly, put both elements into the transition, key them, and use `mode="out-in"`

```
<transition name="flip" mode="out-in">
    <div key="login" v-if="currentForm === 'login'">...</div>
    <div key="register" v-else>...</div>
</transition>
```

Your second problem is the animations, as the two transforms are conflicting, use this instead.

```
.flip-enter-active, .flip-leave-active {
  transition: all .5s;
}
.flip-enter, .flip-leave-to {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(-90deg);
}
```

Here is a very simplified version of your form you can copy to show it working:

```
<template>
<main class="login-body">
  
  <transition name="flip" mode="out-in">
    
    <div key="login" class="login-box" v-if="currentForm === 'login'">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <p>Not Signed Up? <button @click="toggleForm">Sign Up</button></p>
    </div>
    
    <div key="register" class="login-box" v-else>
      <h2>Sign Up</h2>
      <p>Already Signed Up? <button @click="toggleForm">Sign In</button></p>
    </div>
    
  </transition>

</main>

</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "HomeView",
    data() {
      return {
        currentForm: "login",
      };
    },
    methods: {
      toggleForm() {
        this.currentForm = this.currentForm === "login" ? "register" : "login";
      },
    },
  };
</script>

<style>

  .login-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 40px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .flip-enter-active, .flip-leave-active {
    transition: all .5s;
  }
  .flip-enter, .flip-leave-to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(-90deg);
  }

</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, @dantheman. It has fixed the issue of translating down and right by adding the translate(-50%, -50%), although could you explain why this is necessary as I couldn't find this as a solution when looking. The other change I had to make was changing `.flip-enter, .flip-leave-to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(-90deg);
  }` to `.flip-enter-from,
.flip-leave-from {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(-90deg);
}` for the transition to work correctly but now works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: @Chris You're welcome. yeah the naming conventions for vue transitions changes a lot from version to version. The translate issue is because an element can only have one transform property, so when it animates the property gets overwritten and the translate gets removed. So adding that to the animation keeps that styling active. Can you mark the answer as correct if this helped you? :)

Comment: ah that makes sense, thank you. Already marked your answer as correct :)